# Angular JS Refactor Controller Dependency Injections

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am wondering if there is a way to abstract out dependencies that are used across multiple Angular Controllers.

For example, if both my `StudentCtrl` and `TeacherCtrl` take advantage of `$scope`, `$rootScope`, `$routeParams`, and `$http`, is there a way to abstract these out into a package of some sort, say `standardDependencies` and then inject `standardDependencies` into both controllers instead of writing out all of the shared ones?

ex.

```
app.controller('StudentCtrl', ['standardDependencies', function(standardDependencies){

}]);
```

I know this is what services are typically used for I just haven't seen any examples for injecting things like `$scope`, only custom functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this for `$scope` because it might be different for each controller.

Actual singleton-like services, yes, you could technically wrap up into another service:

```
app.service('standardDependencies', ['$rootScope', ..., function($rootScope, ...) {
  this.$rootScope = $rootScope;
  ...
}}]);
```

But I don't see any good reason to do so. If `StudentCtrl` and `TeacherCtrl` are really that similar, maybe they should both depend on something like `PersonService` that wraps common functionality.

Comment: This was a watered-down example, I have 16 controllers and growing and they all share ~6 dependencies (`$rootScope, $rootParams, $location, $http, $translate`); I was just wondering if there was a way to refactor that so I'm not typing the exact same dependecies 16+ times.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably bad practice, but you could define an array `standardDependencies` at the top of `app.js` and then use `array.concat`.

e.g.:

```
// app.js
standardDependencies = ['$rootScope', '$rootParams', '$location', '$http', '$translate']

// controller.js
app.controller('StudentCtrl', standardDependencies.concat(['$q', '$log', etc, 
  function($rootScope, ..., $log){ ... }]);
```

You still have to list them out as function parameters, but at least you don't have to list them twice, once as a string, once as a parameter.

Answer (score -1):

Use some kind of provider; however, this is not very good practice as it might make it difficult for the angular digest cycle to manage these references. This goes against best practices for dependency injection.

If you would like your scopes to access dependencies all across, either a) do proper inheritance of your scopes or b) just do native injection.

I hope that helps. :D